# "Invisible Ink" effect on image using jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, mousehover

I am trying to add "Invisible Ink" effect on image. It is working on the text as shown below in the image.

[image]

I just want the same effect on the image tag, is it possible?

Here is the code I am using for this:

[Source](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/gGzRJv?editors=1010)

**HTML**

```
<div class="flex">
    <div class="content">
        <h2 class="ink">Invisible Ink</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
(function(){
    function wrapWords(el) {
        'use strict';
        $(el).filter(':not(script)').contents().each(function () {
            if (this.nodeType === Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
                wrapWords(this);
            } else if (this.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE && !this.nodeValue.match(/^\s+$/m)) {
                $(this).replaceWith($.map(this.nodeValue.split(/(\S+)/), function (w) {
                    return w.match(/^\s*$/) ? document.createTextNode(w) : $('<span>', {class: 'word', text: w}).get();
                }));
            }
        });
    };


     $('.ink').each(function(){
        $(this).html(wrapWords(this));

        $(this).find('.word').each(function(){
            inkout($(this));
            $(this).addClass('initialized');
        });
    });

    $('body').on('DOMNodeInserted', function(e) {
        if ($(e.target).is('.ink') && $(e.target).hasClass('initialized') == false) {
            setTimeout(function(){
                $(e.target).html(wrapWords(e.target));

                $(e.target).find('.word').each(function(){
                    if(!$(this).hasClass('initialized')){
                        inkout($(this));
                        $(this).addClass('initialized');
                    }
                });
                $(e.target).addClass('initialized');
            }, 100);
        }
    });


    function css( element, property ) {
        return window.getComputedStyle( element, null ).getPropertyValue( property );
    }

    function inkout(element){
        element.parent().css('position','relative');
        var startTime = new Date().getTime();
        var currentTime = startTime / 1000;
        var font = element.css('font-size') +' '+ element.css('font-family');
        var color = element.css('color');
        var text = element.html();

        var particles = [];
        var hoverArray = [];

        var cw = element.width(),
            ch = element.height();
        element.html('');
        var canvas = $('<canvas/>').attr({width: cw, height: ch}).css({display: 'inline-block','vertical-align': 'text-bottom'}).appendTo(element),
            context = canvas.get(0).getContext("2d");

        function drawText(){
            context.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);
            context.fillStyle = color;
            context.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);
            context.font = font;
            context.textAlign = "center";
            context.fillText(text,cw/2, ch - (ch/5));
        }

        $(window).resize(function(){
            element.html(text);
            font = element.css('font-size') +' '+ element.css('font-family');
            particles = [];
            cw = element.width(),
                ch = element.height();
            element.html('');
            canvas = $('<canvas/>').attr({width: cw, height: ch}).css({display: 'inline-block','vertical-align': 'top'}).appendTo(element),
                context = canvas.get(0).getContext("2d");
            drawText();
            scramble();
        });
        drawText();

        function hover(x,y){
            var id = hoverArray.length;
            hoverArray.push([x,y]);

            setTimeout(function(){
                hoverArray[id] = undefined;
            },1300);
        }

        $(document).click(function(){
            hoverArray = [];
        });

        element.parent().on('mousemove touchmove',function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            var x = e.pageX - element.offset().left;
            var y = e.pageY - element.offset().top;
            hover(x,y);
        });


        var particle = function(x,y,visible,color){
            this.color = 'rgba('+color[0]+','+color[1]+','+color[2]+','+color[3] / 255+')';
            this.visible = visible;
            this.realx = x;
            this.realy = y;

            this.toplace = false;

            this.rate = Math.round(Math.random() * 12) - 8;

            this.spin = Math.round(Math.random() * 2);

            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;

            particles.push(this);
        }
        particle.prototype.draw = function(){
            var l = false;
            for(var i = 0; i < hoverArray.length; i++){
                if(hoverArray[i]){
                    if(this.realx >= hoverArray[i][0] - 25 && this.realx <= hoverArray[i][0] + 25 && hoverArray[i]){
                        if(this.realy >= hoverArray[i][1] - 25 && this.realy <= hoverArray[i][1] + 25 && hoverArray[i]){
                            this.toplace = true;
                            l = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            if(l == false){
                this.toplace = false;
            }

            if(this.toplace == false){
                if(this.spin == 1){
                    this.x = this.realx + Math.floor(Math.sin(currentTime) * this.rate);
                } else if(this.spin == 0){
                    this.y = this.realy + Math.floor(Math.cos(-currentTime) * this.rate);
                } else {
                    this.x = this.realx + Math.floor(Math.sin(-currentTime) * this.rate);
                    this.y = this.realy + Math.floor(Math.cos(currentTime) * this.rate);
                }
            } else {
                if(this.x < this.realx){
                    this.x++;
                } else if(this.x > this.realx){
                    this.x--;
                }
                if(this.y < this.realy){
                    this.y++;
                } else if(this.y > this.realy){
                    this.y--;
                }
            }

            if(this.visible == true || this.toplace == true){
                context.fillStyle = this.color;
                context.fillRect(this.x, this.y, 1,1);
            }
        }

        function scramble(){
            for(var y = 1; y < ch; y+=1){
                for(var x = 0; x < cw; x++){
                    if(context.getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data[3] >= 1){
                        if(Math.round(Math.random() * 3) >= 2){
                            new particle(x,y,false,context.getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data);
                        } else {
                            new particle(x,y,true,context.getImageData(x, y, 1, 1).data);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        scramble();
        var requestframe = window.requestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || window.msRequestAnimationFrame || window.oRequestAnimationFrame ||
            // IE Fallback, you can even fallback to onscroll
            function (callback) {
                window.setTimeout(callback, 1000 / 60);
            };
        function loop(){
            var now = new Date().getTime();
            currentTime = (now - startTime) / 1000;
            context.clearRect(0,0,cw,ch);
            for(var i = 0; i < particles.length; i++){
                particles[i].draw();
            }

            requestframe(loop);
        }
        loop();
    }
})();
```

Comment: Could you create a working snippet or demo (jsfiddle, codepen), thanks

Comment: @ovokuro i have just added the Source link, from where i used. Please check